# Removing item from array in useState()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**I am learning react. Need some help to understand this.**

I have two buttons. One "add random text" other is "remove".

For the add button I've used `Math.random` to generate number and added some text with that.

I want to show the list items by mapping it. And when the remove button is clicked the last item will be removed.

I tried `pop()` but that only shows the removed one. How can i keep the whole list and just remove last one?

```
const [data, setData]=useState([]);
let addHandler =()=>{
//Newdata is Math.random()*100+some text
setData([...data, newdata])
}
let removeHandler=()=>{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is you could use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to partition your array from 0 to length - 1

```
let removeHandler=()=>{
    setData(data.slice(0, data.length - 1))
}
```

[`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) should work as well. E.g.

```
data.pop() // removes last element from array
setData([...data]) // clone remaining array
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems like I was doing the pop method in a wrong way. I was adding the popped data in the setData.